# Is there a way to make Premiere reuse nested previews?

Tags: premiere, preview

I have a rather effect-heavy clip in my project. I made it a separate sequence using *nest* from the context menu and rendered its preview to see it's ok.

Now that it's rendered(shows green on top of the timeline), I go to the main sequence and notice that Premiere has to render the nested sequence again.

My question is, is there any way to make Premiere reuse these already rendered previews in a nested sequence either through native settings or a plugin?

I'm using Premiere Pro CC on Win 8.1

Comment: Have you tried running the preview render to see if it does use the existing preview?  It still needs to render the sequence which it is nested in, but that doesn't necessarily mean it won't base it on the already rendered preview rather than recomputing all the effects.  (I don't know for sure what it will do, I'm just throwing it out there as an observation.)

Comment: Judging by the frustratingly long time it takes to do anything with the nested sequence, I'm guessing PP is computing all the effects again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to accomplish this, since you can apply effects on nested sequences as well as to single clips, which means the nested sequence might look different in the main sequence than it does in the nested one. My humble guess is that that is also the reason why Premiere does not use the existing preview files.

A workaround would be to export the nested sequence and re-import the rendered file in your project, replacing the nested sequence. This of course means you won't be able to make changes to that part of your video anymore, as well as a slight loss in quality (unless you export the sequence using a visually lossless codec such as ProRes or DNxHD) ...

Comment: Accepted. Don't like the answer but there's not much anyone can do about this :) I don't see why PP couldn't just render previews for each nesting level separately, so when I change one insignificant effect at the top level, PP wouldn't have to render every damn nesting level with all the effects from bottom up again and again. It's just inefficient and frustrating :)